# How to add Java Class Live Template to generate multiple files in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for my Struts application where each action class must have associated permission class like below,

```
MyAction extends ActionSupport
MyActionPermissions extends ActionPermissions
```

I want to create live file template which will generate both these classes using a single file template.

How can I create such Live template in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: It's not possible without creating a custom plug-in: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91565.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that certainly helps.